# How to expose an Interface with WCF REST?

Tags: .net, wcf-rest

```
// Service file

   [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "Send/{country}", Method = "POST")]
    public int Send(IFoo item, string country)

// Interface file
    public interface IFoo
    {
        string firstMember { get; set; }
        string secondMember { get; set; }
    }

// Implementation file
public class FooImpl : IFoo
{
  string specificMember { get; set; }
}
```

I call my REST service with a post on http://example.com/MyService/Send/{COUNTRY}/
**I want to be able to give an IFoo implementation as a text/xml parameter like :**

```
<FooImpl xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Hello">
  <firstMember>Hello</firstMember>
  <secondMember>World</secondMember>
  <SpecificMember>!</SpecificMember>
</FooImpl>
```

**It works when I declare a FooImpl type in the Send method declaration but it doesn't work when I use the IFoo type.** (Error 400: Bad Request)
The service helper displays :

```
<anyType xmlns:d1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="d1:schema" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" />
```

So, I don't know if it is a xml problem in my parameter or an implementation problem...

Answer (score 0):

**Update**:
Okay, it seems my original assumption was wrong. Even with known types set properly, I get the same error as you are. Apparently, the DataContractSerializer is not used by default, and adding behaviors to select a custom serializer have no effect on REST endpoints. I need to do some further digging...

**Original Post**:
It's a little complicated to use an interface in a service contract, because in the end the data needs to be deserialized into a concrete type: interfaces cannot be instantiated.

The key to the solution is something called *known types*. The DataContractSerializer needs to know about any concrete type that it might run into during (de)serialization.

I've created a little sample that consists of 4 different projects. ClientApp, Interface, Library and Service.

**Interface** contains `IFoo` and `IService`.

**Library** contains `FooImpl`, because both client and server need access to this type. This library is however 'pluggable'. You can add more implementations of `IFoo` on the fly.

Guess what **Service** and **ClientApp** contain :)

The service contract needs the special KnownTypeAttribute:

```
[ServiceContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(IFoo))]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string GetData(IFoo value);
}
```

Now, you can configure the concrete types that implement IFoo in your App.config (or whatever it's called) on both client and server:

```
<system.runtime.serialization>
    <dataContractSerializer>
        <declaredTypes>
            <add type="Interface.IFoo, Interface">
                <knownType type="Library.FooImpl, Library" />
            </add>
        </declaredTypes>
    </dataContractSerializer>
</system.runtime.serialization>
```

If you don't need this pluggable structure, you should be able to use

```
[KnownType(typeof(FooImpl))]
```

instead of this whole elaborate structure.

If I can find the time tomorrow, I'll test WCF REST with this and make the sample downloadable somewhere.

Comment: @Spilarix I did some experimentation, including some scary code to inject a data contract serializer with modified settings. That didn't have the desired effect. Unfortunately I haven't been able to investigate further so far :(